# Validate all required inputs automatically in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms, validation, request

I'm trying to validate a form in Laravel 5 and I want to be able to validate all required inputs in it (as defined in the html via the required attribute) and return a generic error message without having to define every single input field by itself in the code.

Right now it looks like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),
        [
            'input1' => 'required',
            'input2' => 'required'
        ],
        [
            '*.required' => ':attribute is required'
        ]);
```

This works except that I have to manually define every required input field. I would prefer if it was possible to automatically detect all required fields in the request and run it through these same rules.

Comment: Do you mean all fields are required?

Comment: I mean all fields which have the required attribute set in the html form.

Comment: it is always recommended to validate on the server side, if you send the client side validation it is always possible to modify it.